# Non-degenerate scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If a non degenerate scalar product (notation say $<,>$), is defined on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.

can we say that $<v,v> \neq 0 $ where $v\in V$

Comment: What if $v$ is the zero vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that for $v=0$ we have $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$. If we exclude $v=0$, then the answer depends on what your definition of a scalar product is.

If $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is positive-definite, like the usual euclidean scalar product used in geometry, then $\langle v, v \rangle > 0$
for all $v \neq 0$.

If by an inner product you mean a symmetric bilinear form, then, even if $v$ is non-zero, we cannot say that $\langle v, v \rangle \neq 0$. For example, take the hyperbolic plane, that is, $\mathbb R^2$ with the inner product defined as

$$\langle x_1e_1+x_2e_2, y_1e_1 + y_2e_2\rangle = x_1y_1 - x_2y_2$$

(where $e_1, e_2$ is the standard basis), which is non-degenerate.

Then, for $v = e_1 + e_2$, we have $\langle v, v \rangle = 1 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: For me, positive-definiteness is one of the defining properties of an inner product (together with linearity and (conjugate-)symmetry), and so I wouldn't call your example an inner product...

Comment: @DanRust I'd say there's a terminological ambiguity here. E.g. nlab defines an inner product as a synonym to a symmetric bilinear form: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inner+product+space

Comment: True, I guess the OP should clarify their definitions.

Comment: @DanRust On second thought, the term "scalar product" used by OP most probably refers to the usual positive-definite case. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DanRust as per my reference(lang's linear algebra) : A scalar product on $V$ is an
association which to any pair of elements $v,w$ of $V$ associates a scalar,
denoted by $<v, w>$, with the property that  $<v, w> =  <w, v>$ and the linearity condition. The cases of non degenerate and positive definite are told seperately.